# Using Type parameter in Scala Functions

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement the Boolean Type in Scala, and i found an example using this signature :

```
abstract class Boolean {
   def ifThenElse[T](t : => T , e : => T) : T

   ... }
```

My questions is :

1. When we should use the type Parameter after the function name like this funcName[T].
2. What does t : => T  mean ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As for the first question:

> 1.When we should use the type Parameter after the function name like this funcName[T]

if you want this function can be used by different type, it's appreciate that put the generic type after function name as `funcName[T]`. For example, you have a function like this

```
def myFunction[T](param1: T){/*process*/}
```

you want to pass the parameter `param1` and `param2` to `myFunction`. These two parameters are defined as following

```
val param1: Int = 10 
val param2: String = "test"
```

Though `param1` and `param2` have different types, you can call the function `myFunction(param1)` and also `myFunction(param2)`

Then, let's talk about the second question

> 2.What does t : => T mean ?

It's a `by-name parameter`.  what's it? The following gives you more details:

`t: => T` has the same meaning as `t: () => T`, instead of inputing the words `() => T`, you can choose `=> T` as for `t`

Another example: if you want to has an assertion, you may define the function like this:

```
def myAssert(predicate: () => Boolean) = 
    if(!predicate()) throw new AssertionError
```

then you can use it as following

```
myAssert(() => 5 > 3)
```

The usage is so ugly, is it? You may want to use it like this

```
myAssert(5 > 3)
```

at this time, the `by-name parameter` will be on the stage. Just define your function by the help of `by-name parameter`

```
def myAssert(predicate: => Boolean) = //leave out '()'
    if(!predicate) throw new AssertionError //leave out '()'
```

then, you can use `myAssert` as above

```
myAssert(5 > 3)
```

**Notes**: A by-name type, in which the empty parameter list, (), is left out, is only allowed for parameters. There is no such thing as a by-name variable or a by-name field.

Good luck with you.

Comment: (1) `def compare[T](num1: T, num2: T): Boolean ...` is not a good example, unless you want to compare hash codes since you don't know anything about type `T`. Containers are better examples with no type bounds. (2) In the first `def myAssert ...` you are supposed to write `if(!predicate())`, functions require explicit parentheses.